# How to specify the default installation profile

Tags: 7, distributions

I want to specify my custom installation profile as default one, like acquia profile in acquia drupal.

For example when installing acquia drupal, acquia profile will be selected by default thus choose profile and language will be skipped. Now I need to overcome this, because I'm, writing my installation profile in the acquia drupal. So I should set my custom profile as the default one instead of acquia profile.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops its my mistake.

D7 by default doesn't consider standard and minimal profiles, so its selects acquia profile by default.

I had problem with my custom installation profile, that's why it doesn't showed up in the profile list.